# How to write Junit test cases for a Thread class

Tags: java, multithreading, junit, mockito

I have a class MyThread which either extends Thread or implements Runnable interface. The MyThread class constructors and some private methods and `run()` method defined.

What is the right way to write junit test cases for the class? Can I write test cases for the `run()` method by directly invoking it within test methods or should I create an instance of the thread and do `thread.start()`?

Comment: I think you should not use Unit Test for concurrency but integration tests.

Comment: The ultimate goal is just code coverage and integration test. And I am not worried about test for concurrency.

Comment: A Thread should be very simple. You may want to outsource the real logic in to a seperate class and call this within the hread. Then you could easily write code coverage tests with JUnit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't extend Thread. Implement Runnable. Test the run() method the same way you would test any "ordinary" method.

The obvious benefit of this approach is that you don't need to deal with concurrency at all.